# getting error "The template parameters are invalid." while launching a dataprep template from composer

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using the below code :

===============================================

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataflowTemplateOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.models import Variable

PROJECT = Variable.get('gcp_project')
print("project"+PROJECT)
TEMP_BUCKET = Variable.get('stg_bucket')
TEMPLATE = "gs://*************"
INPUT_FILE = "{\"location1\":\"test:random.Summary\"}"
OUTPUT_FILE = "{\"location1\":\"test:random.TestSummary\"}"
PARAMETERS = {
    'inputFile': INPUT_FILE,
    'outputFile': OUTPUT_FILE
    }

TODAY = datetime.today()
TODAY_STRING = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': TODAY,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'schedule_interval': '@hourly',
    'dataflow_default_options': {
               'project': PROJECT,
               'region':'us-west1',
           'zone': 'us-west1-b',
               'tempLocation': TEMP_BUCKET
           }
}

dag = DAG(
    'Demo-DAG-DataflowTemplate',
    default_args=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=1)
    )

start = DummyOperator(task_id='inicio', dag=dag)
end = DummyOperator(task_id='fim', dag=dag)

t1 = DataflowTemplateOperator(
    task_id='dataflow_template_launch',
    template=TEMPLATE,
    parameters=PARAMETERS,
    dag=dag)

start >> t1 >> end
```

====================================================================================================
However, I am getting issue while running the DAG. The error says:

returned "The template parameters are invalid."

I am able to run the same template using normal python code but when I am using the DataflowTemplateOperator , its not executing. Can some one please help me on this?

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778309/how-to-deal-with-the-template-parameters-are-invalid-when-launching-a-custom-t

Comment: i tried removing templocation, but its giving the same error. Also, i cannnot add customGcsTemplocation as a parameter.its not accepting

Comment: @jjayadeep..in case you have ever used it, can you please share the code..

Comment: You can take a look here for an end to end example - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-orchestrate-cloud-dataprep-jobs-using-cloud-composer.