# "Error 400: The template parameters are invalid" - Running Dataflow Flex Template via Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to run a [Dataflow Flex Template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) job via a Cloud Function which is triggered by a Pub/Sub message.

However while the Dataflow pipeline works fine when running it from gcloud / locally in the command line / via the [Google Flex Template API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.flexTemplates/launch), when I try to launch it as a Google Cloud Function I keep running up against this error:

```
"Problem running dataflow template, error was:  { Error: The template parameters are invalid."
```

[image: cloud-dataflow-stack-trace]

To note, I'm using all the same parameters as when I was testing it, and I've attempted to remove / reformat them all on a few occasions, and have passed them in as their actual strings rather than environment variables.

Now I had seen that this was due to [incorrect formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778309/how-to-deal-with-the-template-parameters-are-invalid-when-launching-a-custom-t) and/or using the [incorrect parameter key names](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6961#issuecomment-674901885) themselves - possibly because I've used Python to build the pipeline, and Node.js to run the cloud function i.e. "temp_location" vs "tempLocation" or similar.

Or I was wondering whether having set `google_cloud_options` in my main.py  file doesn't allow me to specify them as a JS friendly argument when using the template at runtime?

But having tried various combinations this doesn't make much difference. So my question is: does anyone know a fix for this issue, alternatively does anyone know how to even try to debug which parameters are wrong? Do I need to be passing my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` service-account.json file as well?

Is the problem simply that the Cloud Function needs to be written in Python as well as the Dataflow pipeline?

#### Google Cloud Function

```
# trigger.js
const { google } = require("googleapis");

exports.triggerFlexTemplate = (event, context) => {
  // PubSub message payloads and attributes not used.
  const pubsubMessage = event.data;
  console.log(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage, "base64").toString());
  console.log(event.attributes);

  google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error occurred: " + err.toString());
      throw new Error(err);
    }

    const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: "v1b3", auth: authClient });

    const date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

    dataflow.projects.locations.flexTemplates.launch({
        projectId: projectId,
        location: process.env.region,
        resource: {
          launchParameter: {
            jobName: `rank-stream-to-bigquery-${date}`,
            containerSpecGcsPath: `gs://${process.env.bucket}/dataflow_templates/rank_stream_to_bigquery.json`,
            parameters: {
              api_key: process.env.api_key,
              date: date,
              campaign: process.env.campaign,
              se: process.env.se,
              domain: process.env.domain,
              project: process.env.project,
              dataset: process.env.dataset,
              table_name: process.env.table_name,
              runner: process.env.runner,
              experiments: "disable_flex_template_entrypoint_override",
              staging_location: `gs://${process.env.bucket}/staging`,
              temp_location: `gs://${process.env.bucket}/temp`,
              service_account_email: process.env.service_account_email,
            }
          }
        }
      },
      function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
        } console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
      });
  });
};
```

#### Dataflow Pipeline

```
# main.py
from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import
import argparse
import logging
import sys

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
from apache_beam.metrics.metric import Metrics
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions, SetupOptions, WorkerOptions

import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta, date
import time
import re

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

SCHEMA = {'fields': [{ 'name': 'date', 'type': 'DATE', 'mode': 'REQUIRED' },
                     { 'name': 'url', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE' },
                     { 'name': 'lp', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE' },
                     { 'name': 'keyword', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REQUIRED' },
                     { 'name': 'se', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REQUIRED' },
                     { 'name': 'se_name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REQUIRED' },
                     { 'name': 'search_volume', 'type': 'INTEGER', 'mode': 'NULLABLE' },
                     { 'name': 'rank', 'type': 'INTEGER', 'mode': 'NULLABLE' }]}

class GetAPI():
  def __init__(self, data={}):
    self.num_api_errors = Metrics.counter(self.__class__, 'num_api_errors')
    self.data = data

  def get_job(self):
    import requests
    params = dict(
        key = self.data.api_key,
        date = self.data.date,
        campaign_id = self.data.campaign,
        se_id = self.data.se,
        domain = self.data.domain,
        output = 'json'
    )
    endpoint = "https://www.rankranger.com/api/v2/?rank_stats"
    logging.info("Endpoint: {}".format(str(endpoint)))
    try:
        res = requests.get(endpoint, params)
        if res.status_code == 200:
            json_data = res.json()
            if 'result' in json_data:
                response = json_data.get('result')
                filtered = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v != '-' and len(v) != 0} for d in response]
                return filtered

    except Exception as e:
        self.num_api_errors.inc()
        logging.error('Exception: {}'.format(e))
        logging.error('Extract error on "%s"', 'Rank API')


def format_dates(api):
    import datetime as dt
    api['date'] = dt.datetime.strptime(api['date'], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    return api


def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--api_key',
        type=str,
        help='API key for Rank API.')
    parser.add_argument('--date',
        type=str,
        help='Run date in YYYY-MM-DD format.')
    parser.add_argument('--campaign',
        type=str,
        help='Campaign ID for Rank API')
    parser.add_argument('--se',
        type=str,
        help='Search Engine ID for Rank API')
    parser.add_argument('--domain',
        type=str,
        help='Domain for Rank API')
    parser.add_argument('--project',
        type=str,
        help='Your GCS project.')
    parser.add_argument('--dataset',
        type=str,
        help='BigQuery Dataset to write tables to. Must already exist.')
    parser.add_argument('--table_name',
        type=str,
        help='The BigQuery table name. Should not already exist.')
    parser.add_argument('--bucket',
        type=str,
        help='GCS Bucket name to save the temp + staging folders to')
    parser.add_argument('--runner',
        type=str,
        help='Type of DataFlow runner.')

    args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    wo = options.view_as(WorkerOptions)  # type: WorkerOptions
    wo.worker_zone = "europe-west1-b"

    google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    google_cloud_options.project = args.project
    google_cloud_options.staging_location = "gs://{0}/staging".format(args.bucket)
    google_cloud_options.temp_location = "gs://{0}/temp".format(args.bucket)
    google_cloud_options.region = 'europe-west2'
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = args.runner

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

    api = (
        p
        | 'create' >> beam.Create(GetAPI(data=args).get_job())
        | 'format dates' >> beam.Map(format_dates)
    )

    BQ = (api | "WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                                table=args.table_name,
                                                dataset=args.dataset,
                                                project=args.project,
                                                schema=SCHEMA,
                                                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))

    p.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I really don't think that the language or variables could cause this error. I would suggest to first try out this locally and set your sdk with application credentials. Once you master sending the request, this will help you to try different configuration and analyze better why the request is failing. There should be an error from using the google.dataflow but I have never used it before, but it seems to be an attribute missing from the library call. Besides this, if your authentication wasn't right, you would get a 403 code.

Comment: Agree, try it, even create a direct API call with CURL to look at the difference between your code and the CURL content